# CGRectIntersectsRect not always detecting collisions

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've created an app where images fall from the sky and I have to "catch" them on the bottom with a user-moveable basket. I put the falling images and the basket image in CGRectMake frames and used CGRectIntersectsRect to detect for collisions. However, it's not detecting every collision. For example, I'll have visually "caught" 10 objects, the two frames definitely intersected, but it will only say I caught 2. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code for the bucket:

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];

  ```
  basketView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bucket.png"]];
  basketView.frame = CGRectMake(130.0, 412.0, 30.0, 30.0);
  [self.view addSubview:basketView];
  ```

  }

Here is the falling object and collision code:

```
- (void)onTimer
{
    UIImageView* appleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:appleImage];


    int applePosition = round(random() % 320); //random starting x coord
    double scale = 1 / round(random() % 100) + 1.0; //random apple size
    double speed = 1 / round(random() % 100) + 1.0; //random apple speed


    appleView.frame = CGRectMake(applePosition, -100.0, 25.0 * scale, 25.0 * scale);

    [self.view addSubview:appleView];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(__bridge void *)(appleView)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3 * speed];


    appleView.frame = CGRectMake(applePosition, 500.0, 25.0 * scale, 25.0 * scale); 


    // Test for landing in bucket
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(basketView.frame, appleView.frame)) {
        collision++;
        printf("%i\n", collision);
        [appleView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I made the basket huge, and now I'm getting spammed numbers and no apples are showing up. So I'm assuming that it's only checking for intersection with the apple at its starting point, not during the actual animation. How can I make it check for intersection DURING the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously if your timer function spawns new objects, the test will be done exactly after the creation of the object, so if the object is not actually created in the basket, your hit test will always be negative.

Now, you need another timer which will test for collisions every 10th of a sec or so (depending on how fast you move your objects, this could be more or less). An even better option (form the performance point of view) is to use `CADisplayLink` which works pretty much like a timer only it allows you to synchronise your tests to the refresh rate of the display.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! I created the second timer (which I presumed should be within void(onTimer)):

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.01) target:self selector:@selector(onCollisionCheckTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Within onCollisionChecktimer I put the collision test. However, how can I test the appleView.frame for collision when it was declared in void(onTimer)?

Comment: You don't need to create a second timer every time the spawn timer ticks. Create it just once. As for the accessing problem, you need to keep an array of all of your objects and test them all when the second timer ticks.

Comment: I put the second timer in [super ViewDidLoad]; then placed each newly spawned apple into an array. In the new timer selector (which will fire every 0.001 seconds), I created a 'for' loop that goes through indices 0-100 of the array and checks each time  for         if (CGRectIntersectsRect(basketView.frame, appleView[index].frame)). Is this what you meant?

Comment: yes, although 0.0001 is probably an overkill, 0.1 would do good. Also, you need to use the for loop to go through all objects (e.g. if you have only 2 apples, the for goes from 0 to 1, if you have 10, from 0 to 9, you get the idea